# Use string function to select all text after specific character

Tags: coldfusion

How would I use use a string function to select everything in a variable after the last "/"

http://domain.com/g34/abctest.html

So in this case I would like to select "abctest.html"

Running ColdFusion 8.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

Um, a bit strange to give very similar answer within few days, but `ListLast` looks as most compact and straightforward approach:

```
<cfset filename = ListLast("http://domain.com/g34/abctest.html","/") />
```

And yes, IMO you should start with [this page](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/functions-pt0_01.html) before asking such questions on SO.

Comment: The list functions are very powerful. The trick is looking at strings and figuring out who to make them lists.

Answer (score 0):

Joe I'd use the listToArray function, passing the "/" as the delimiter, get the length of the array and get the value in the last slot. See sample below

```
<cfset str = "http://domain.com/g34/abctest.html"/>
<cfset arr = ListToArray(str,"/","false")/>
<cfset val = arr[ArrayLen(arr)]/>
<cfoutput>#str# : #val#</cfoutput>
```

produces

http://domain.com/g34/abctest.html : abctest.html